# Highcharts constant spacing between marks

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stock

Can you please tell me how to make a constant width between timestamps in Highcharts (as in the screenshot), with scaling for the chart interval, and how can I shift the chart itself to the left?

[Screenshot of the result I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKT0p.jpg)

I made a demonstration of what I get with my data, the intervals are placed in an incomprehensible manner and are not very beautiful

```
var tz=Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
var date = new Date();

var series = {
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 4
    },
    id: 'aapl-ohlc',
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: [],
    fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
            [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
    },
    threshold: null
}

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    time: {
        useUTC: false,
        timezone: tz,
    },
    chart: {},
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true,
        seriesThreshold: 5
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'minute',
            count: 5,
            text: '5m',
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert('Clicked button');
                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'minute',
            count: 10,
            text: '10m'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 6,
            text: '6m'
        }, {
            type: 'ytd',
            text: 'YTD'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
        },
        height: '80%',
        resize: {
            enabled: true
        },
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        },
        top: '80%',
        height: '20%',
    }],
    xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
        max: date.getTime() + 60000*2,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lastVisiblePrice: true,
        },
        pointWidth: 145
    },
    series: [series]
});

$.get('https://searchyoutb.com/data.php', function(response) {
    chart.series[0].setData(response);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gashik100/3h50rcjo/11/

I would like help with my problem

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts Stock, the `ordinal` property is set to `true` by default for the xAxis, which ensures that the distance between the points is equal, regardless of the actual time difference between them.

If you want the ticks to have the same spacing between each other, just set:

```
xAxis: {
  ordinal: false
}
```

This demo illustrates it nicely: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xref6g19/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can you tell me how to move the chart to the left from the Y-axis, so that the time series continues along the axis?
I tried this option
let lastElem = data[data.length - 1];
for(var i=0;i<=2;i++){
     data.push([lastElem.date+30*i*1000, null]);
}
This option is not suitable because I want to display the last price
         lastVisiblePrice: {
             enabled: true
             color: '#FFF',
             label: {
                 enabled: true
             }
         },
but it is not displayed because the last value is null

Comment: I want to get a view like in the screenshot in the question

Comment: You can use `xAxis.max` property and set some value greater than the last point has. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.max